# Creating a sections polygon layer from tic points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, excel, plss

I am working in Arcmap v10.3.  I'm trying to create a "sections" (PLSS) layer from the section corners (tics).  I know I could convert the points to X,Y coordinates and use the coordinates to create lines.  But I can't figure out what order they will need to be arranged in the table to create squares from the lines.
Another route would be to take the state provided PLSS layer (which in inaccurate) and snap those polygon corners to my tics (the tics have been placed manually using imagery).

Comment: What does your input data look like?  You have a tag for [tag:excel] so I am guessing it is an Excel file but what are the fields and the values from a few rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue.  I figured out that I could create a line layer from the State provided PLSS polygon layer.  To removed extra vertices from the line layer: I merged all lines, planerized all lines, then generalized all lines with a tolerance smaller than that of the shortest section line.  Then I used the "snap" tool (making sure to select the "vertices" option for snapping) and snapped the lines layer to the master tic layer.  Then make a polygon layer from the new line layer.  (extra step: for QA purposes, I then used the "vertices to points" tool to create a tic layer from my new lines.  I then used the "symmetrical difference" tool to make sure the mastertics and the new tic layer were the same).  I then collapsed the original PLSS layer to points and spatially joined those points to my new polygon layer to retain the attributes.